# Maven fails to pull down latest Selenium Java jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to simply add the latest Selenium 2.44.0 to my project in IntelliJ, for some reason it's happy with 2.42.0 but 2.44.0 errors with

"Dependency '''org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.44.0''' not found"

Any ideas what's going on? My POM in its entirety:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test.testproj</groupId>
<artifactId>twitterati</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3
        </version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: did 2.43 works, and did U update maven repository ???

Comment: No, I cannot update with any other version.  I am also trying from command line with mvn clean install but the error is: "failed to collect dependencies at org.seleniumhq...."  I am beginning to think it is a firewall / network issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First try running on the command line by forcing an update.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

If that fails, try the same after removing your local repository and check the contents of your ~/.m2/settings.xml file and let us know if there is anything in there.

And then if that still fails .. see if you can ping the Maven repository. (repo1.maven.apache.org).

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the project, Select maven-->Reload the project this shall reload and download the dependency you have problem with.

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure you are not passing the offline option to Maven by accident ( -o ) and also make sure nothing exists in your settings.xml file that might reroute your repository location.

Comment: @manfredmoser - thanks both. Looks like I forgot about a rogue settings.xml which had a mirror to a Nexus repository.  Now, I just need to sanitise the settings file - how is it best to do so?

Comment: I usually just comment out any relevant section in the settings.xml  but you might be able to override it by 'explicitly' defining 'maven central' in a 'repositories' section directly in your pom.xml ?  It is worth trying...